# Assigning values to same lists, but get different results

Tags: python

I create two same zero lists. Yet the results are different when the lists are assigned to same values. Here are my code and result.

code:

```
m1 = [[0] * 4] * 4
m2 = [[0 for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
m1[0][1] = 1
m2[0][1] = 1
print('m1:', m1)
print('m2:', m2)
```

result:

```
m1: [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]
m2: [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Or maybe the two lists are not the "same"? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `m1` has 4 references to one list.

Comment: Try `m1[0] is m1[1]` and `m2[0] is m2[1]` and see the diference

Comment: m1[0] is m1[1] → True; m2[0] is m2[1] → False. Now I see the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `m1`, you're referencing the same `[[0] * 4]` 4 times. Basically you're doing:

```
x = [0, 0, 0, 0]
m1 = [x, x, x, x]
x[1] = 1
```

resulting in x being `[0 1 0 0]`
and being repeated 4 times in `m1`

Comment: I get it. Thank you.